# pandasでグループごとの箱ひげ図を作る方法

Tags: python3, pandas, matplotlib

pandasにて、下のようなデータを写真のような箱ひげ図で表すにはどうすればよいですか？

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
     'group':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'], 10),
     'test1':np.random.randint(1, 100, 10),
     'test2':np.random.randint(1, 100, 10)
     })
```

[image]

```
groupby
```

を使って、

```
grouped = df[['group', 'test1', 'test2']].groupby('group')
grouped.boxplot(subplots=False)
```

とすると似たようなグラフが出来るのですが、写真のように分類ごとの区別が分かりやすい箱ひげ図を作りたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: pandasではなくmatplotlibとかグラフ作成側の記事ですが、こんなのが参考になるかも。[matplotlib: Group boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16592222/9014308), [Data Viz with Python and R](https://datavizpyr.com/grouped-boxplots-in-python-with-seaborn/), [How to group Matplotlib boxplots in Python](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-group-matplotlib-boxplots-in-python), [Plotting boxplots for a groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44152180/9014308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seabornでの例です。
データフレームの構造を変更しています。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
     'group':np.random.choice(['A','B','C'], 20),
     'test':np.random.randint(1, 3, 20),
     'score':np.random.randint(1, 100, 20)
     })
df = df.sort_values('group')
sns.boxplot(x='group', y='score', hue='test', data=df)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]