# seabornで箱ひげ図を複数作成して表示したい

Tags: python, matplotlib

## 問題

以下のようなDataFrameがあるとします。

| index | 都道府県 | 建物 | 価格 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 東京 | 木造 | 100 |
| 1 | 東京 | 鉄骨 | 120 |
| 2 | 東京 | 木造 | 100 |
| 3 | 埼玉 | 鉄骨 | 80 |
| 4 | 埼玉 | 木造 | 80 |
| 5 | 埼玉 | 鉄骨 | 90 |
| 6 | 東京 | 鉄骨 | 90 |
| 7 | 東京 | 鉄骨 | 130 |
| 8 | 埼玉 | 木造 | 100 |
| 9 | 埼玉 | 木造 | 60 |

このDataFrameを都道府県ごとにxを建物の種類yを価格にして箱ひげ図を描きたいです。
しかし、sns.boxplotを利用してsubplotを利用する方法が調べてもいまいちわかりませんでした。

どのようにすればできるでしょうか？

最終的にはこの例の場合、東京で木造と鉄骨の2つの箱ひげ図が1つのグラフに、埼玉で木造と鉄骨の2つの箱ひげ図が1つのグラフに描かれた1×2のグラフが作成したいです。

以下のコードで上記のDataFrameは作成可能です。

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# データフレームの準備
pref = ["東京", "東京", "東京", "埼玉", "埼玉", "埼玉", "東京", "東京", "埼玉", "埼玉"]
house = ["木造", "鉄骨", "木造", "鉄骨", "木造", "鉄骨", "鉄骨", "鉄骨", "木造", "木造"]
value = [100, 120, 100, 80, 80, 90, 90, 130, 100, 60]
df = pd.DataFrame({'都道府県':pref, '建物': house, '価格':value})
```

私は以下のように行っていましたが、途中であきらめてしまいました。
もっと良い方法がありそうです。

```
pref_list = df["都道府県名"].tolist()
pref_list = set(pref_list)

structure_list = df["建物"].tolist()
structure_list = set(structure_list)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(7, 7, figsize=(50, 50))
j = 0
for i, pref in enumerate(pref_list):
    for s in structure_list:
        if j == 7:
            j = 0
        ax = i // 7
        ax1[ax][j].set_title(pref)
        ax1[ax][j].boxplot(df[(df["都道府県名"]==pref) & (df["建物"] == s)]["取引価格（総額）_log"])
        ax1[ax][j].set_xlim(0, 3)
        ax1[ax][j].set_ylim(2, 10)
    
    j = j + 1
plt.show()
```

これでは、`seaborn`が使えず困っています。subplotが7×7なのは都道府県が47都道府県本来あるので、そのようにしています。
`このコードは動きません`

わかる方教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seaborn.boxplot()` 内でデータをフィルタリングして(`data=df[df.都道府県==p]`)、東京と埼玉のデータを別々の `ax` に振り分けます(`ax=ax[i]`)。

```py
sns.set(font=['IPAPGothic'])
_, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
ylim = (50, 150)

df = df.sort_values(['都道府県', '建物'])
for i, p in enumerate(('東京', '埼玉')):
  sns.boxplot(
        x='建物', y='価格', data=df[df.都道府県==p], ax=ax[i])\
     .set(xlabel=p, ylim=ylim)

plt.show()
```

[image: 出力結果]

#### 追記

> subplotが7×7なのは都道府県が47都道府県本来あるので、そのようにしています。

subplot が `7x7` の場合、`ax` が 2 次元の配列(numpy.ndarray)になるので要素(subplot のインスタンス)へのアクセスの仕方が異なります。具体的には tuple によるアクセスが可能なので `ax[divmod(i, cols)]` の様にします。

```py
pref_list = df.都道府県.unique()

# Japanese font
sns.set(font=['IPAPGothic'])

# subplots
rows, cols = 7, 7
_, ax = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(40, 40))
ylim = (50, 150)

# plot all
for i, p in enumerate(pref_list):
  sns.boxplot(
        x='建物', y='価格',
        data=df[df.都道府県==p].sort_values('建物'),
        ax=ax[divmod(i, cols)])\
     .set(title=p, xlabel=None, ylim=ylim)

# hide excess graphs
for i in range(len(pref_list)-rows*cols, 0):
  ax[-1, i].axis('off')

#plt.show()
plt.savefig('boxplots.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
```

[image: boxplots]

Comment: とても丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

以下を参考にしてみました

- (ja.stackoverflow.com) [pandasでグループごとの箱ひげ図を作る方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72535/)
- (stackoverflow.com) [pandas-dataframe-groupby-plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494942/)

(フォント指定や, 余った部分の消し込み・その他がないのでコード量少なそうだけど, 処理加えるとそれなりの大きさになっていきます)
`grouped.ngroups` を計算か何かに利用するかもしれないので, 先に group化し描画
複数行の plotでもエラーにならないよう, `flatten()` してます

```py
grouped = df.sort_values('建物').groupby('都道府県')
_, axes = plt.subplots(7, 7, figsize=(50, 50))
for key,ax in zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axes.flatten()):
    sns.boxplot(x='建物', y='価格', data=grouped.get_group(key), ax=ax).set_title(key)
```

Comment: ありがとうございました！